# C++ Destroying struct from inside of it

Tags: c++, console

so I have a struct bullet:

```
struct Bullet {
    int posX; int posY;
    int verticalBulLimiter = 0;
    int verticalBulLimiterCheck = 35; // aka movement Speed

    void draw() {
        gotoxy(posX,posY);
        setColor(14);
        cout << bullet << endl;

        if (posY - 1 == 0){
            /// I want to delete struct here
        }

        if (verticalBulLimiter == verticalBulLimiterCheck) {
            posY--;
            clearPixel(posX, posY + 1);
            verticalBulLimiter = 0;
        }
        else {
            verticalBulLimiter++;
        }

    }
};
```

as You can see I want to delete the struct once it's variable posY reaches certain value. 
So how do I do that. Do I tried using keyword "this" but I dont really know how does it work. Is there any function for 'self destruction' ?

Comment: You can use `delete this`

Comment: @Asesh Nooooooo.  You can only do that in very specific circumstances and even then it is really frowned upon.

Comment: @Staley, are these bullets in some container or exist as variables in some other object?

Comment: @Stanley The problem is, up to the moment where the `struct` would destroy itself, something somewhere has some way of referring to it, at least to call `draw`. If your `struct` destroys itself, you have to consider what happens to that pointer (or whatever is used to refer to your `struct` instance). If your `struct` destroys itself, you likely have a dangling pointer. So you need to notify your object's owner in some way. But, if you do that, you might as well just offload the responsibility of destroying the object to it anyway.

Comment: @NathanOliver nah since its not ready I just declare one bullet in int main() to test it. Im planing to store all the bulelts in a vector. I am aware that if I would do so I can just remove them from vector but id prefer to do this kind of self destruction since I dont have to worry about indexes

Comment: @François Andrieux man Im not so advanced in C++ yet to understand all of this. Are you saying that I should just store them in vector/array and erase them from athat container once i dont need them?

Comment: @Stanley That's generally how it works. But it doesn't solve the main question of when/who erases the element from the container. It's unusual but sometimes correct to have the object remove itself from the container. You have to be super careful because that implies a member function that invalidates it's own `this` pointer half way through. It's generally considered a Bad Idea. Maybe a safer solution is to have the object add itself to a list of elements "to be cleaned up" or otherwise flagged so the erasing can be done outside of your struct.

Comment: `Bullet() {
        bulletsOnScreen.push_back(this);
    }` is This a good idea adding struct to a list like this?

Comment: Add this member variable to Bullet:  `bool garbage = false;` In the code that wants to delete it, add `garbage = true;`  When the owner throws out the garbage, it can check the garbage flag of all the Bullets, and delete those which are garbage.

Comment: If you destroy the struct at the point you describe, subsequent code in the function will have undefined behaviour, due to accessing members of the struct you just destroyed. An alternative is to change `draw()` to return a `bool`, and return either `true` or `false` (you choose) if the object should cease to exist. The caller of `draw()` then checks the return value, destroys the object, and cleans up. How it does that obviously depends on how the structure was created in the first place.  Most objects don't have information about how they were created, so cannot destroy themselves cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

While this can be possible using `delete this`, it is most definitely not what you want.

Objects in C++ do not usually own themselves, so you should have the owner of the bullet (maybe a scene or world entity) delete it.

Comment: Okay, delete this; doesnt really do the job. So I declared the object in int main(); am I to understand that whom is the owner of that bullet?

Comment: Variables declared at function scope are owned by the function. They cease to exist when the function returns. If you declare a `Bullet` in `int main` it will exist for the entire duration of `main`. In addition, if you declare an object with automatic storage (like `Bullet my_bullet;`) then it's always an error to `delete` it. This is one of the reasons `delete this;` is bad. You aren't always allowed to do that.

Comment: @Stanley Objects in C++ are either created on the stack (`Bullet my_bullet`) or on the heap (`Bullet *my_bullet = new Bullet`). Objects on the stack are deleted whenever they go out of scope, objects on the heap have to be explicitly deleted via `delete my_bullet`. You should not use raw `new` and `delete` though.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to "destroy a struct from within", you should be checking and removing instances of struct that have met some conditions. 
There's an algorithm that does just that, like so.

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Bullet { ... };

std::vector<Bullet> bullets;

void clean_bullets(){
      bullets.erase(
        std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(),
        [](const Bullet& i){return /* your condition when a bullet should be removed */}),
        v.end()
      );
}


int main(){
   // Add some bullets
   bulltes.push_back({/* create a bullet here */});
   .
   .
   .
   clean_bullets();
}
```

The `std::vector<Bullet> bullets` contains all the bullets, and is responsible for memory, removing, adding elements etc.

You can read more about `std::vector` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

And about removing the elements like above, it's called the remove/erase idiom https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove

Comment: I wish this was the right answer. But giving lambda-using code to OP who is at the point of understand lifetimes and scopes might not be the best way to go

Comment: I agree that this code may be confusing to new developers. I believe this answer would be greatly improved if `clean_bullets` was broken down into smaller steps, at least separating `remove_if` to it's own line. Another simple change may be to use a free function instead of a lambda function (maybe presented as an alternative to illustrate the behavior of the solution using a lambda).

Comment: It gives me some errors anyway, but I kinda udnerstand approach and Ill try to do this using tools I know